# Why is there an aircraft carrier model in the Enterprise briefing room?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, uss-enterprise

The briefing room in The Next Generation has a variety of starship models on the wall, presumably of different classes of Starfleet ships.  But why is (what looks like) an aircraft carrier included with the models?  (In the screenshot, the aircraft carrier is on the lowest row, furthest to the right)

[image: Enterprise Briefing Room Models]

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Those are all ships throughout history that have been named *Enterprise*.  We see, that we know of, ships from the original series and movies on that wall.  We do not see the NX-01, since that had not been thought of at that point.  The aircraft carrier is the [U.S.S. *Enterprise* (CVN-65)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_%28CVN-65%29), which currently has a home port in Norfolk, VA, USA.

Comment: Is the [Space Shuttle Enterprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Enterprise) on the wall? Ok, it never flew, but...

Comment: @draks I know you see a picture of the shuttle in 1979 Movie http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Motion_Picture

Comment: The space shuttle Enterprise wasn't a real space shuttle. It was only used for test flights within the atmosphere. Perhaps that would have excluded it from the wall.

Comment: @draks: Technically, the shuttle _Enterprise_ flew.  Just never under its own power and it never took off.  But I remember watching on TV when they detached it for the first time and let it glide to Earth.  Gliders fly all the time -- just not with their own power.

Comment: Point of fact: The *Enterprise* was the nuclear carrier Chekov and Uhura boarded in *Star Trek IV*. But the scenes in (and of) the ship used the non-nuclear *USS Ranger*.

Comment: If Star Trek had been made by Lucas, he would have gone in digitally for the re-release and added the NX-01, the XCV-330, the 5 sailing ships, the second aircraft carrier Enterprise, and any other ship ever bearing that name up through the NCC-1701D

Comment: Given the super-structure shape, you're right.  Though, I guess I'm a little more familiar with [the one from WWII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(CV-6)), which is the one I was thinking of.

Comment: @X-Zero: Then I guess the question would be, "Why didn't they include the original flat top _Enterprise_?"

Comment: @Gieron: It certainly was (and still is) "a real space shuttle", despite the fact it never flew _in space_. It would have been pretty useless as a test vehicle if it weren't "a real space shuttle".

Comment: In reality, the space shuttle was named partly in honor of the ship from Star Trek.  In Star Trek, that logic wouldn't make sense, so in-universe the space shuttle has a different back story, probably went to space, and Kirk's ship was named in honor of the shuttle rather than the other way around.

Comment: @BBlake And if it had been made by Spielberg, he would have replaced all the phasers with communicators...

Answer (score 3):

Gene Roddenberry's obsession with the Navy.
The ship display chronicles past ships named Enterprise. 
There were 14 British Navy ships named Enterprise in 300 years
9 in the US Navy (including two Aircraft carriers)
One space shuttle
One XCV prototype warp vessel
One NX class (Not named with USS prefix)
And Five Federation Starships (Enterprise A-E, not including F and J, as those vessels have not made canonical apperances, the Enterprise J was the result of a future event)
[image]

Comment: That image for the CV-6 *Enterprise* doesn't look like it, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(CV-6)